# How to set subsections to custom alpha listing

Tags: sectioning

```
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\alph{subsection}}
```

The above line set subsections to alpha listing, so if I had `subsection` A, then using `\subsubsection{}` would result in `A.1, A.2, ...` and so forth.

However, how can I modify the command so that I can have `subsubsections` that are `A.1.1, A.1.2, A.1.3, ...`?

Comment: No. You probably mean `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}`, from which both `\subsection` and `\subsubsection` follows as you'd expect.

Comment: Currently, I'm using `\renewcommand\thesubsection{\Alph{subsection}}`. But I'm looking for `\subsubsection` to be labeled as `A.1.1, A.1.2, A.1.3...` Should I define a command for `\subsubsubsection` instead?

Comment: it is hard  to answer if you just provide fragments of code and loose descriptions. latex already defined two levels of heading below subsubsection called `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph`. By default the subsubsection numbering would not be A.1 as you show but would show three levels for section.subsection.subsubsection.  So your problem is in code you have not shown.

Comment: @Adrian: In `A.1.2`, what level does `A`, `1` and `2` represent respectively? Typically, `A` = `\section`, `1` = `\subsection` and `2` = `\subsubsection` (if you exclude using a class that has `\chapter`s). Are you using `\chapter`s? You should, ideally, provide us with a minimal document that replicates your current behaviour. This is a small piece of compilable code that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`. Can you do that?

Comment: You may find it helpful to annotate the output of the complete document that I [posted in my answer and say what output you want (unless that is already the output you want, in which case we are done)

Comment: @Adrian: From the accepted answer, it's clear that you just weren't able to number `\subsubsection`s in your document and that the actual question was to increase `secnumdepth`, which is covered in the duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very hard to answer as the declaration that you show does not produce the output you describe so it is not clear what you need to change.

Just using the definition of `\thesubsection` that you give does not produce a numbering A.1 at any level.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\alph{subsection}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\begin{document}

\section{section one}

\subsection{ssection one.one}
zz
\subsection{ssection one.two}
zz

\subsubsection{sssection one.two.one}
zz

\subsubsection{sssection one.two.two}
zz

\paragraph{para one.one.two.two.one}
zz

\paragraph{para one.one.two.two.two}
zz

\end{document}
```